# Sqlite in memory, temp memory file is not getting deleted

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite in memory mode and on connection closure, the temporary memory file is not getting deleted automatically.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

Comment: Sample code snippet is: Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");

Comment: An in-memory database does not create a file. What file are you talking about?

Comment: It actually does create a file https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html. Quote on this temp file "Even though a disk file is allocated for each temporary database, in practice the temporary database usually resides in the in-memory pager cache..."